# Margins with Material cardview not work - spacing does happen

Tags: android, material-design

I got pretty simple code but for some reason margins for cardView not working. I was using this guide

https://m2.material.io/components/tabs/android#fixed-tabs

Here is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="main"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="description"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weather_main" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather_temp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="temp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weather_description" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather_pressure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="pressure"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weather_temp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather_humidity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="humidity"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weather_pressure" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather_wind_speed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="windSpeed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weather_humidity" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
```

Here is how it looks like. But it should have margins on a cardView as on the link example
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the card view inside the ConstraintLayout and then add padding in the card view or margins in the views.

try this way

Comment: could you please share code what you mean?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).